# Apply css to selected component from global style in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngx-bootstrap

I need to apply some CSS to a component that creates content dynamically. I can't use the CSS file for the component because of that. I can define the style in the global style sheet I have but that will apply to all the other components as well where I don't want it. Is there a way to achieve this?
The specific element I am looking to style is , it is added as a new element dynamically and has no parents specific to this component.

Answer (score 0):

add an unique id for that element which include in that component . then verify your styles in the "style.css" file

Comment: Please read the question, the content is being created dynamically I cant add any ids or classes etc to it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).